# "ng serve" Process stays frozen after initializes (at 18%)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5, package.json

I have tried all the steps listed in the solutions in here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

The process starts normally and stays frozen here:
`18% building modules 71/79 modules 8 active ...media/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js`

Already tried un/installing angular-cli and the whole package json like a million times

Comment: Is your project small enough to upload it to some place? (and that we can take a look)

Comment: Yes! I haven't done much, I was just setting it up :( https://github.com/Nikodermus/nikodermus.media/tree/v2 (Branch v2)

Comment: Where in there is your Angular site?

Comment: Branch v2, I have just updated the link

Comment: The latest version of the CLI is missing some stuff , you will need to manually run:  npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/core

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, seems some npm package is missing (try doing a fresh clone of your project, maybe you installed an `npm` package without the `--save` or `--save-dev` as someone points out above?

Comment: Thank you guys, found the problem, I was getting in a infinite loop since in _mixins I was requiring _variables, and in _variables requiring _mixins, had to do revert commit and try out every change, whoever answers first get's the reputation, you were all of help :D